# what is the API for the read() function on aggregates?

Tags: wolkenkit

The references in using command services on the writeModel use this example:

```
const commands = {
  async issue (invoice, command, { app }) {
    const otherInvoice = await app.accounting.invoice(otherInvoiceId).read();

    // ...
  }
};
```

ok... what if what I need to do is really *search* the current or other aggregates for data? Are there filter options etc. that can be passed to read() or something to accomplish that? If not, how does one do what I'm asking?

Comment: Hey ! Did my reply answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

In the write model (which is where commands are handled), an aggregate can only be referenced by its id. Hence the sample code that you provided is actually the only viable way to `read` an aggregate from the write model, and the `read` function does *not* have any additional arguments.

If you need to perform a *search*, you might want to access the read model. As in CQRS, the write and the read model should be independent of each other, it is often regarded to be a bad practice to access the read model from within the write model (among other reasons, this is primarily because of consistency issues due to eventual consistency). Hence, wolkenkit does not provide a way to access the read model from the write model.

What you might want to do instead is to perform the search from the client, *before* you are sending a command, and then send the desired aggregate id or ids as part of the command, so that you can then access them in the write model by their id.

I hope this helps.